# ASP.NET Gridview column based display

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to use a GridView to display data in up to three columns per row. For example, lets say you has 9 records of data, and all the data fits in one column. I would want the GridView to show 3 rows with three columns. If it was 5 records, there would be 2 rows in the GridView. One with three columns and one with two.

I'm wondering if this is something that can be handled declaratively or is code needed?

Comment: It sounds like you should use a repeater control instead of a gridview to achieve this functionality.

Comment: As jfmags said, use a Repeater to output the data. Use css, e.g.,  `float:left;`, to stack the items horizontally and continue on to the next row when the current row runs out of space. Maximum number of items per row depends on the width of the container you put them in or the width of the user's window if you don't provide a container.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting groupItemCount=3
in the GridView's property.